# How vulnerable is Opera using a version of Chromium that is 3 versions behind?

Tags: web-browser, chromium

Uses Chromium 115 when current stable is 118. They do claim to have the latest chromium security updates.

Does patching old chromium with the latest security fixes bring it on par with the latest chromium version?

[image: Play Store]

Answer (score 2):

> Does patching old chromium with the latest security fixes bring it on par with the latest chromium version?

Porting security patches back to some older release is commonly done by many software vendors. Sometimes it is done because their own software depends on this older release, sometimes one might selectively only apply significant bug fixes instead of introducing new behavior (and maybe new bugs) which come with a new release. For examples see [“Don't break Debian” and bug fixes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201335/dont-break-debian-and-bug-fixes) or [False positive Apache version in scanner results on Centos](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47711/false-positive-apache-version-in-scanner-results-on-centos).

Properly done this backporting works and fixes the security issues as good as the original fix. If it is properly done in this specific case is not known though. Sometimes such backports are simple since the relevant part of the code did not change much. But this is not always the case and in these cases failures are more likely.